# which is better in my php project?1 table with several empty fields 1 table with several empty fields?

Tags: php, mysql, database

which is better in my php project?

a. 1 table with several empty fields:

table_a:

[image]

b. or 2 tables with any empty fields:

table_b_1 , table_b_2 :

[image]

Comment: It depends on logic you need.

Comment: entirely depends upon your requirements.

Comment: i would recommend the second one

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve from this, maybe we can assist from that perspective

Comment: Please don't obfuscate and/or hide data from your questions. Ask exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what your priorities are.
Also, it would be better to tell us exactly what those two fields are instead of *obfuscating your data*.

**Extreme Speed (Avoiding Joins):**

If your main requirement is **speed**, then it is better to use one table. However this is only in the case that speed is such a large requirement you want non-normalized data.

**Proper Normalized Tables:**

If your main requirement is not having redundancy, and following conventions, you should use the two tables as this provides a more normalized solution causing avoidance of redundant data.

Looking at `table_a`, I notice wherever there is a `name`, there is no `price`, and wherever there is a `price` there is no `name`. Based on this it seems as if you have combined two different entity's/concepts/tables into one. This seems almost like the results of a report (using outer join).

**Finally:**

In order to help you better, we need to know what `field1` and `field2` are, in addition to **what data the whole table holds** in order to understand the context better. Without this information we are basically guessing and can only offer simple guidelines.